# Comparing two worksheets and appending data from one sheet to another if the headers are the same

Tags: excel, vba

Like the name on the tin, I am trying to combine two sets of data by headers in excel using VBA. I am looping through two lists of headers and finding headers that match, if they do I want to append data from the "qrm" sheet to the "ov" sheet. unfortunately I keep getting a non-distinct 1004 error related to the actual copying and pasting portion of the loop. Any ideas why or what I have done wrong? Thanks!

```
Sub testr()

Dim headers As Range
Dim qrmheaders As Long
Dim ovheaders As Long
Dim ovsheet As Worksheet
Dim qrmsheet As Worksheet
Dim lRowOv As Long
Dim lRowQRM As Long


       'get headers as vars for each sheet
        Set ovsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("requisition")
        lRowOv = ovsheet.Cells(ovsheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        ovheaders = ovsheet.Cells(1, ovsheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set qrmsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("qrm req")
        lRowQRM = qrmsheet.Cells(ovsheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        qrmheaders = ovsheet.Cells(1, qrmsheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
       ' for each header in qrm headers
        ' for each header in ov headers
                'if qrm = ov then
                    'get position of qrm header data
                    ' paste qrm data below ov data using lRow+1
       For i = 1 To qrmheaders
            Set qrmCell = qrmsheet.Cells(1, i)
            For j = 1 To ovheaders
            Set ovCell = ovsheet.Cells(1, j)
                If ovCell.Value = qrmCell.Value Then
                    With qrmsheet
                        .Range(.Cells(2, i), .Cells(lRowQRM, i)).Copy Destination:=ovsheet.Range(j & lRowOv + 1)
                    End With
                    End If
            Next j
        Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: `.Cells(.Rows.Count, i)` is the last row on the sheet row 1,048,576. You are missing the `.End(xlUp)`

Comment: `Range(j & lRow + 1)` probably s/b `Range(lRow+1, j)`?

Comment: `Range(j & lRowOv + 1)` is probably not what you want. If `J = 1` and `LRowOv = 10` then your final number would be 111.

Comment: `Destination:=ovsheet.Cells(lRowOv + 1,j)`

Comment: Changed `Destination:=ovsheet.Cells(lRowOv + 1,j)` as well, however, still getting the same error. Hmm.

Comment: What is the exact error and which line. Your code works fine for me with a simple data set.

Comment: Number of columns are same on both the sheets? `qrmheaders = ovsheet.Cells.....` should be `qrmheaders = qrmsheet.Cells...` ?

Comment: Also, `Exit For` could be added before `End If` to exit inner loop once the column headers are matched and data is copied to `ovsheet`.

Answer (score 0):

These were all great suggestions and I am surprised it worked for some of you at all. The change that was needed was to use `.Cells` as opposed to `.Range` method while pasting. It seems to be a common issue among folks to try to use that method.

Below is the code that worked for me:

```
Dim headers As Range
Dim qrmheaders As Long
Dim ovheaders As Long
Dim ovsheet As Worksheet
Dim qrmsheet As Worksheet
Dim lRowOv As Long
Dim lRowQRM As Long


       'get headers as vars for each sheet
        Set ovsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("requisition")
        lRowOv = ovsheet.Cells(ovsheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        ovheaders = ovsheet.Cells(1, ovsheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set qrmsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("qrm req")
        lRowQRM = qrmsheet.Cells(ovsheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        qrmheaders = qrmsheet.Cells(1, qrmsheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
       ' for each header in qrm headers
        ' for each header in ov headers
                'if qrm = ov then
                    'get position of qrm header data
                    ' paste qrm data below ov data using lRow+1
       For i = 1 To qrmheaders
            Set qrmCell = qrmsheet.Cells(1, i)
            For j = 1 To ovheaders
            Set ovCell = ovsheet.Cells(1, j)
                If ovCell.Value = qrmCell.Value Then
                    With qrmsheet
                        .Range(.Cells(2, i), .Cells(lRowQRM, i)).Copy
                    End With
                    With ovsheet
                        .Paste Destination:=ovsheet.Cells(lRowOv + 1, j)
                    End With
                    End If
            Next j
        Next i
End Sub
```